# How can I call a function of UIViewController from its reference on a different swift file?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have got my current `visibleViewController` on a swift file:

```
let currentController = self.navigationController?.visibleViewController
```

and I have a function on the swift file associated to the actual `UIViewController` called `chargeData`.

What I am trying to do is to call that function from the first file but I am not able to do it. I tried doing:

```
currentController.chargeData()
```

but an error is shown:

> Value of type 'UIViewController?' has no member 'chargeData'

I can guess from the error log that of course it is not recognizing the swift file in which the actual `UIViewController` is associated.

So what should I do to access to the function of my actual `UIViewController` from its reference?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to typecast your currentController variable in order to call any method you created on your own.

```
let currentController = self.navigationController?.visibleViewController as? YourViewController //Here YourViewController is the name of the UIViewController subclass you created
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much! It is exactly what I wanted :)

Answer (score 1):

You're not far away: you have access to the view controller, but Swift doesn't realize what type it is – it thinks it's a plain `UIViewController?` when really you know it isn't.

What you need is a typecast. If your class was called `ViewController`, you would write this:

```
if let currentController = self.navigationController?.visibleViewController as? ViewController {
    currentController.chargeData()
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It is exactly what I needed. I am sad that I could not mark more than one option as accepted. Upvote instead :)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to cast your `currentController` from `UIViewController` to your specific type, then you can use Objective-C's `performSelector`:

```
let selector = Selector("chargeData")
if currentController?.respondsToSelector(selector) == true {
    currentController!.performSelector(selector)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let currentController = self.navigationController?.visibleViewController
```

NavigationController's VisibleViewController method return UIViewController Type so your method is not find in UIViewController.

```
let currentController = self.navigationController?.visibleViewController as! YourVC.
```

Now you can call your method.

In Swift Type is not implicitly find.